# horizontally collapsible panel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a side collapsible panel that include `StackPanel`

[image]

For that Tried use `Expander` like following

```
<Expander Width="auto" ExpandDirection="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Expander.Header>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">                       
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>                  
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>    
        </Border>
    </Expander.Header>
</Expander>
```

But this is not working properly, can't do the function that I expected.

Comment: If you want your expander on the left, then HorizontalAlignment should also be left. And the contents you want to show/hide should be inside Expander.Content, not Expander.Header.

Comment: what you suggested giving same output I put xml content inside `Expander.Content` and changed `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`

Answer (score 6):

As Maciek Świszczowski said, you need to properly align your expander and put the contents inside the context section of the expander.  Also, assuming you want it to fill the entire left section, I would recommend you use a `Grid` to hold it all, like so:

Example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Expander ExpandDirection="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        </Border>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Here's what it looks like (I put a blue background and some text in the expander, and just a red stack panel in the second column in order to make it really clear).

Expanded:
[image: Expanded]

Collapsed:
[image: Collapsed]

Comment: I realize that this is a very old question, but it was the first hit when I searched for "horizontally collapsible expander", so I thought I'd post the answer I came up with.